# MYSQL Remote access php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a project on a hosted server. They are very unreliable so I have decided to move to another host. In the interim I want to leave the php files on the existing server and point them at another MySQL database on my rackspace server. I have configured the mysql on the rackspace server to accept remote connections. I can successfully connect to it via the terminal from my ubuntu at home. However every time the php files on the hosting server try to connect to it I get the error below :

This is the code in the php....

```
mysql_pconnect("1.2.3.4","user","password")
or die("Unable to connect to SQL server".mysql_error());
```

This is the error/output

> Unable to connect to SQL serverLost connection to MySQL server during
>   query

Any ideas why I can connect via the terminal but not from php ?

Thanks

Comment: would a few hours of down time be unacceptable?

Comment: Not all hosting servers allow this.  Rackspace or your hosted server may be blocking remote MySQL.

Comment: What error code do you get by modifying your die method:
die("Unable to connect to SQL server".mysql_error()." Error-Code: " .mysql_errno);

Answer (score 0):

Check your [wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout). Set it to a high number while you are doing your move .

Comment: I was thinking of just moving all the php to my rackspace and pointing the DNS of the domains at that IP. Probably the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the connection is refused immediately then either your old or your new hosting providers are blocking the connection, or you have a problem with the host mask on the user account you're using to connect. You could try fsockopen() to try directly connecting to see if the connection is refused if you don't have access to command line mysql clients at the old host to try and identify which of these is the case. If it's blocked after a timeout, it's almost certainly a firewall policy at one or both ends.

However, can I just say that:

a) mysql_ functions are deprecated, so you should probably also look at upgrading to mysqli or pdo or something.

and

b) unless you tell whatever api you're using to connect with SSL or some other secure method (in the mysql_ case it's the MYSQL_CLIENT_SSL flag) your data (and possibly your password or some variation on it that could let attackers connect as you) will go over the open internet unecrypted... of course, this requires an SSL certificate or is vulnerable to man in the middle attacks, so... yeah.